# Using array and Function in for loop

Tags: c, matrix

There is a code that converts Relations to Matrix

When I compile it, it gives 2 errors. I debugged it but can't find real reason.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
int i=0,j=0,k=0;
char a[] = "12345";
char b[] = "abcde";
char r[] = "1c2b3e4d5a";
// Array Long
int LA = sizeof(a)-1;
int LB = sizeof(b)-1;
int LR = sizeof(r)-1;


   //index function

int index(char arr[],char v){  // [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
    for(k=0;k<sizeof(arr)-1;k++){
        if(arr[k]==v){
        return k;
        }
    }

}


// trying printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",LA,LB,LR);


int rel[LA][LB];

for(i=0;i<LR;i+=2){
    int indexa = index(a,r[i]);
    int indexb = index(b,r[i+1]);
    rel[indexa][indexb]=1;
}


//print the matrix 

for(i=0;i<LA;i++){
    for(j=0;j<LB;j++){
        printf("%3d",rel[i][j]);
        }
    printf("\n");
}

return -1;
} //[Error] expected '}' at end of input
```

How can I solve this problem?

Errors:

> [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
>   [Error] expected '}' at end of input

I convert this code from a java code: [Converting Relation to Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30289769/converting-relation-to-matrix)

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Also, it does not really seem to be java code, more like c.

Comment: You cant define a function inside main body

Comment: I show the errors in the code after  // points.

Comment: one thing i notice at least in your for-loop k<sizeof(arr) - 1. you should propably either have <= or skip the -1

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define a function inside a function in C, and your current code attempts to define `index` inside `main`. Move it before `main`'s definition and you should be OK:

```
int index(char arr[],char v) {
    for (k = 0; k < sizeof(arr) - 1; k++) {
        if (arr[k] == v) {
            return k;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    // code goes here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks errors get out. But Outputs are not like I want.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that in `C` you cannot define functions inside functions
what you are doing here is that you defined the `index()` function inside the `main()` function and that's why you got errors.

Try this code snippet below, hope it fixes your problem

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

//index function
// [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
// [SOLUTION] You can't define a function inside of a function in c
int
index (char arr[], char v)
{
  int k = 0;
  for (k = 0; k < sizeof (arr) - 1; k++)
    {
      if (arr[k] == v)
    {
      return k;
    }
    }
}

int
main ()
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  char a[] = "12345";
  char b[] = "abcde";
  char r[] = "1c2b3e4d5a";
// Array Long
  int LA = sizeof (a) - 1;
  int LB = sizeof (b) - 1;
  int LR = sizeof (r) - 1;


// trying printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n",LA,LB,LR);

  int rel[LA][LB];

  for (i = 0; i < LR; i += 2)
    {
      int indexa = index (a, r[i]);
      int indexb = index (b, r[i + 1]);
      rel[indexa][indexb] = 1;
    }


//print the matrix 

  for (i = 0; i < LA; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < LB; j++)
    {
      printf ("%3d", rel[i][j]);
    }
      printf ("\n");
    }

  return -1;
}

//[Error] expected '}' at end of input:
//[SOLUTION]: again you can't define a function inside of another function
```